# .NET binary backward compatibility

Tags: .net, backwards-compatibility

Why can't older version of .net compiled binaries run on newer version of framework, like java 'binary' compiled under jdk 1.3 runs fine under jre 1.6 ?

With mixed reference library requiring various .net runtime, the installation base size of application is large.

Comment: In very many cases, older versions of .NET binaries absolutely *can* run under newer versions. If you've got a *specific* situation in mind, you should ask about it.

Comment: As Jon said, most of the time this is not a problem. You just need to indicate which runtimes your application supports with the [`supportedRuntime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) config.